# Powershell trim text using a special character

Tags: powershell

I have a list of hostnames which have the domain and subdomian in the FQDN. I need to get only the parent (root) domain name from it.

I have tried with substring but have not succeeded.

```
abc.xyz.me.com
def.me.com
ghi.sub.new.com
jkl.sup.old.com
```

these are some examples and from the list and I would like to get the root domains (me,new,old).

Answer (score 1):

The simple way would be to use split and get the index of -2

```
$FQDN = ('abc.xyz.me.com', 'def.me.com', 'ghi.sub.new.com', 'jkl.sup.old.com')

ForEach ($Domain in $FQDN)
{
write-host ($Domain.split(".")[-2])
}
```

You probably want to do more than just write to host, but that should give you the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Split the string, reverse the array and then pull the second member

```
$list = @(
  "abc.xyz.me.com",
  "def.me.com",
  "ghi.sub.new.com",
  "jkl.sup.old.com"
)

$List | ForEach-Object {
    [Array]::Reverse(($Arr = $_.Split(".")))
    $TLD, $SLD, $Null = $Arr

    $TLD # You're top level domain
    $SLD # The second level domain
    # The rest of the values after those two get sent to null land
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that gets a unique list of the full parent domains into a variable named `$ParentDomains`:

```
$Domains = 'abc.xyz.me.com', 'def.me.com', 'ghi.sub.new.com', 'jkl.sup.old.com'

$ParentDomains = $Domains | ForEach-Object {
    $Domain = $_.Split('.')
    $Domain[-2]+'.'+$Domain[-1]
} | Get-Unique

$ParentDomains
```

**Explanation:**

- Iterates through the list of domains via `ForEach-Object`. Each domain in the loop is represented by `$_`.
- Splits the string on the '.' character
- Uses the index indicator `[]` to get the second to last `[-2]` and last `[-1]` items in each array and outputs them as a new string separated by a '.'.
- Pipes the result to `Get-Unique` to remove duplicates.